# <span> in <a> vertically not aligned

Tags: html, css

I would like to have a `<ul>` inside my `<nav>`, in which I need to have a `<span>` inside an `<a>` tag.

The problem here is that the first `li` is vertically not aligned with others and this gives something ugly.
After exploring a bit with the F12 I saw that the `span` tag was higher than the `a`. Here is a quick preview of the render

[image: render].

The table display is here so that space is correctly distributed to each li (I have 5)

I tried to change the position of the `span` and of the `a` but it didn't work.

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #dfc8b3;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

ul {
  display: table-row;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  display: table-cell;
  font-size: large;
}

a.navlist {
  color: black;
  float: top;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined"
      rel="stylesheet">

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="navlist"><a href="index.html#" class="navlist"><span class="material-symbols-outlined">home</span></a></li>
    <li class="navlist"><a href="" class="navlist">li 1</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) - I made you one now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### There is a problem with your icons

When displayed exactly as you have shown in your code, we see only text, and that is correctly aligned.

The explanation for your misalignment in your local code is that your icons are different in height. The `vertical-align: middle;` CSS option will correct the position.

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

ul {
  display: table-row;
  background: #dfc8b3;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  display: table-cell;
  font-size: large;
}

a.navlist {
  color: black;
  float: top;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,0,0" />

<nav>

  <ul>
    <li class="navlist"><a href="index.html#" class="navlist"><span class="">home</span></a> </li>
    <li class="navlist"><a href="" class="navlist">li 1</a>No Icon</li>
  </ul>
<p></p>

  <ul>
    <li class="navlist"><a href="index.html#" class="navlist"><span class="material-symbols-outlined" >home</span></a></li>
    <li class="navlist"><a href="" class="navlist">li 1</a> With icon</li>
  </ul>

<p></p>

  <ul>
    <li class="navlist"><a href="index.html#" class="navlist"><span class="material-symbols-outlined" style="   vertical-align: middle;">home</span></a></li>
    <li class="navlist"><a href="" class="navlist">li 1</a>Icon + vertical-align: middle</li>
  </ul>



</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this css property indeed fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use flexbox for ul element. like this

```
ul {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}
```